# Can I set android background colour based on a variable?

Tags: java, android, background-color

This is my code:

```
private LinearLayout erBackground;
erBackground = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.erBackground);

String background = "YELLOW"
erBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.background)
```

What would I need to do to background to allow it to change the background to yellow?

The above is a simplified version of my code. What I am trying to do is pass an item from a spinner ("YELLOW") on one activity to Shared Preferences, and then onCreate of the next activity I want to check if a background is stored in Shared Preferences.. if it is then change the colour to this.

OnClick code:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

editor.putString("background", personaliseBackgroundSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase());
editor.putString("font", personaliseFontSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase());

editor.commit();
```

OnCreate code of the next activity:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();


String background = pref.getString("background", null); // background = "YELLOW"

if (background != null) {
    erBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.);
}
```

The shared preferences part works though, my problem is that it doesn't let me use a variable after color and wants me to use a color name, but what if the color changes? Do I have to a big long if else statement for each color?

Edit:
XML layout for second activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/erBackground">

<TextView
    android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed neque lacus, tempus eget ultrices id, efficitur id metus. Suspendisse convallis quam vel orci congue lobortis. Praesent et venenatis tortor. Nam non venenatis erat, eget tempus metus."
    android:id="@+id/erUserResultsTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/erSubmitBtn"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Instead of name if you can use color code then you can do like this `Color.parseColor(background); `

Comment: try this... erBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(background));

Comment: @VivekMishra I am getting the variable from a spinner so I want the user to be able to read what color they're selecting, unless I can somehow have a value that I show in the spinner associated to a colorcode value?

Comment: @aksacha thanks for this, it has worked but the background of my text hasn't changed. is there an attribute like textbackground that I need to change too? see what it looks like here: http://i.imgur.com/FZKQSzJ.png

Comment: for this problem you have to change the background color of your TextView also.

Comment: you can keep a mapping of color in your app. Show name to user and load corresponding hex code of color

Comment: @aksacha is there a way to change it for more than one text view on an activity? like changing the style attribute or something like that?

Comment: @VivekMishra ahh okay, can you explain how I would do that?

Comment: @user2633709 have look on my Edit answer.......I think it solve your problem......... Enjoy coding.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String background = "#fff" //whatever color you want to put here put in hex 
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("background",background );
editor.putString("font",   personaliseFontSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase());
editor.commit();
```

On Next `Activity`

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
String background = pref.getString("background", null);
if (background != null) {
erBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(background));
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, it has worked but the background of my text hasn't changed. is there an attribute like textbackground that I need to change too? see what it looks like here: i.imgur.com/FZKQSzJ.png

Comment: Are you putting this `TextView` in seprate `Layout`?

Comment: Post your `XML` of `SecondActivity`

Comment: try `erBackground.setBackground( getResources().getColor(yourcolor));`

Answer (score 2):

Use this code......

```
  erBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW)
```

Color is class and **YELLOW** is **int** not **string**......

Please review this before using color:-http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Color.html

use this code for your problem.....

**declare this variable as global.......**

```
int color[]={Color.YELLOW,Color.GREEN,Color.BLUE,Color.RED,Color.BLACK};

String spinnerText[]={"Yellow","Green","Blue","Red","Black"};//set it to the spinner values


> use the same pattern for the spinner in same order as color.
> Get the position of the spinner and set it in color array variable. like  `erBackground.setBackgroundColor(color[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()]);`
> It is save lots of code of yours.
```

Enjoy Coding...........

Comment: Hi thanks for this but I want to swap it based on a variable. So yellow isn't always going to be the color. It could be blue/red/etc... so I don't want to use code specifying use this color. One way I can think of is doing an if else for all colors but that seems like overkill

Comment: no, I need to set the color based on a variable. In your answer it is hard coded as yellow. if the string for the color is stored in a variable how would I then set the background color to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a HashMap for mapping color hex code and name . For eg.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.putString("Black","#000000");
map.putString("White","#FFFFFF");
```

Pass the color name that you get from your spinner and get corresponding value of that name

```
String value=(String)map.get("Black");
```

and to set as background you can do like this

```
erBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(value));
```